# Does band-limited imply continuous?

Tags: fourier-analysis, continuity, harmonic-analysis

I was hoping someone could point me to an article or text which explores the connection between the continuity of a signal
in the time domain and it being band-limited in frequency domain.

(Update)

- Band limited is defined as: There exists a finite frequency, $\omega_{0}$, such that  $\mathcal{F}\left( \omega \right) = 0$ $\forall\omega$ where $\left| \omega \right| > \omega_{0}$.
- There is no assumptions regarding support for $\mathcal{F}(\omega)$ within the frequency domain or assumptions regarding membership of $f(t)$ in spaces such as $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $S(\mathbb{R})$, or $S^{'}(\mathbb{R})$
- For the context of this question: signal is any function or any distribution which admits a Fourier transform.

(end update)

For example there are two papers entitled: Band-Limited Processes in Discrete and Continuous Time:

http://www.le.ac.uk/ec/research/RePEc/lec/leecon/dp11-11.pdf (24 pages), and
http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/SIGNALS/LODZ.pdf (54 pages)

Weaving throughout the first is the assumption that signals which are band-limited in the frequency domain are continuous
in the time domain and the longer paper is even bolder by stating on page 2 that:

```
A band-limited function is analytic. It possesses derivatives of all orders.
```

While I agree that `sharpness" of any`edges" within a band-limited function must be related to the highest frequency present in the signal, I can't find
any discussion the in the signal analysis literature which describes when and if

```
A function/signal band-limited in the frequency domain is continuous in time domain.
```

I arrived at this question via the examination of almost periodic functions (a.p.)  which are band-limited to the rationals in the interval $[-1,1]$
and (more generally) almost periodic functions which have a fintie basis set where each base is band limited; i.e. where frequencies with a particular base are connected by rationals found within a finite interval.
Example of such functions would be:

$f_{1a}(t) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( -1 \right)^n}{n} \cos\left( 2 \pi \frac{t}{n} \right)
$

$
f_{1b}(t) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cos\left( 2 \pi \frac{t}{n} \right) 
$

$
f_{2a}(t) = \sum\limits_{q = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( -1 \right)^q}{2 \phi\left( q \right) \; q} 
\sum\limits_{\substack{k = 1 \\
 \left( k, q\right)=1}}^{q} \cos\left( 2 \pi \frac{k}{q} t \right)
$

$
f_{2b}(t) = \sum\limits_{q = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \phi\left( q \right) \; q} 
\sum\limits_{\substack{k = 1 \\
 \left( k, q\right)=1}}^{q} \cos\left( 2 \pi \frac{k}{q} t \right)
$

$
f_{3}(t) = \sum\limits_{q = 2}^{\infty}
\sum\limits_{\substack{k = 1 \\
 \left( k, q\right)=1}}^{q} 
a\left(k, q\right)
\cos\left( 2 \pi \frac{k}{q} t \right)
$

$
f_{4}(t) = 
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}
\sum\limits_{\substack{r_{i} \in \mathbb{Q} \\
 \left| r_{i} \right| \le B_{n}}}
a\left(n, r_{i} \right)
e^{2 \pi i \left( \beta_{n} r_{i} \right) t }
$

where:

$\left( k, q\right)$ is the least common divisor of $k$ and $q$

$\phi\left( q \right)$ is the Euler Totient function.

$N$ is a finite integer $1 \le N$

$r_n$ is the set of all rational numbers within the closed interval: $\left| r_{i} \right| \le B_{n}$

The set $\left\{ \beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, \beta_{2}, \cdots, \beta_{N-2}, \beta_{N-1}, \beta_{N} \right\}$ is the finite basis of the almost periodic function function defined by $f_4$.

The definition of the basis set of an a.p. function is found on page 34 of Almost Periodic Functions by A. S. Besicovitch

$B_{n}$ is a positive, finite limit, $0 < B_{n} < \infty$, on the frequencies, $\lambda_{i,n} = r_{i} \beta_{n}$, of the almost periodic function defined by $f_4(t)$

All of the example signals have point-wise convergence (except 1b and 2b at $t=0$)

The Fourier transform of each of the signals above is a set of 
Dirac-$\delta$ distributions which are band-limited to the interval, $[-B,B]$; where $B = 1$ or $B = \text{max}\left( B_{n}\right)$. 
Such a Fourier transform form a band-limited, ``bed--of--nails".

The questions before me are:

1. Are signals with a typical, band-limited Fourier transform (i.e. not
   a ``bed--of--nails") continuous (analytic)? Under what conditions?
2. Are signals with a band-limited, ``bed--of--nails" Fourier transform
   continuous (analytic)?
3. If some such signals are continuous
   (analytic) and others are not, then under what conditions?
4. What are
   the necessary (sufficient) conditions for the signal to be
   continuous (analytic)?

I was hoping someone could pointing me to an article or text that explores the connection (if any) between continuity and band-limited.

Is there theorem similar to the Paley-Wiener theorem, but for functions which do not belong to $L^2$?

Is this question a variation of the Gabor limit?  since a ''Bed of Nails" Fourier transform has no local support, then the signal must have local on the whole of the real line?

Comment: Related: [Fourier series of almost periodic functions and regularity](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49206/856)

Comment: I'm a little confused by the comment "not making any assumption regarding membership in well behaved spaces".  If your signal $f$ is not, say, a tempered distribution, how will you even define its Fourier transform?

Comment: But I think you could prove the following: Suppose $f$ is a tempered distribution, so that its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ makes sense as another tempered distribution.  If $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported (in the usual sense for distributions), then $f$ is equal (in the sense of distributions) to a continuous function.  In particular, if $f$ is a measurable function, then there is a continuous function $g$ with $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @NateEldredge $L^1$ Fourier transform is more classical than the tempered distribution one. One can define that purely through the integral transform. In particular there are some much naughtier functions in $L^1$ than in the Schwarz space.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Indeed, but I am not clear from the question that we are assuming $f \in L^1$.  Basically I would like the word "signal" in the question to be precisely defined.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "my examples lack support in the frequency domain"?  Normally the support of a function is the smallest closed set outside which the function takes the value zero, so every function necessarily has a support.

Comment: One more issue: in the update, you can't mean $\omega = 0$ for $|\omega| > \omega_0$ since it is absurd for a number with absolute value greater than $\omega_0$ to equal 0.  Perhaps you meant $\hat{f}(\omega) = 0$?

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree on that for sure. Generally--especially from an engineering standpoint--they mean something like $L^1$ because they like to use the integral transform rather than the more abstract definition on, for example, $L^2$ et cetera.

Comment: The reason I posted the question is that in my number theory research I keep running into function which have Fourier transforms that are band-limited ``beds of nails".  I also run into papers such as those of Pollack which make broad statements about the properties of band-limited (continuous, smooth, well-tempered, analytic) without citing or providing any proof.  Invariably these signal-approach papers then only discuss functions that are square integrable (i.e. finite-energy).  I suspected there were additional, unstated conditions beyond being used in papers such as Pollock's.

Comment: @NateEldredge I corrected my typing error in the update on band limited, clarified my understanding of signal from the two papers, and yes, *I* am specifically interested in distributions which are *not* absolutely integrable; i.e. $f \notin L^1$.

Comment: I thought ``support" requires the closed set where the function is not equal to zero to be a set with a measure greater than zero.  I see now I was mistaken.  All the examples provided have compact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. Since band-limited means "compactly supported Fourier transform." All you have to do is find a function which has compact support and is in $L^1$ and take it's inverse Fourier transform and modify it a bit. Such an example is

$$f(x)=e^{-x^2}\cdot 1_{[-1,1]}$$

Then this will be a continuous function, but you can modify this choice by doing

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)+1_{\Bbb Q}$$

which has the same Fourier transform, but is clearly discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: When one talks about an $L^p$ function being smooth/continuous, one ordinarily means that there is a representative (w.r.t. equality almost everywhere) with this property.

Comment: @PhoemueX I'm aware, but since the op has such an engineering background, he might not know what are standard counterexamples in mathematics.

Comment: I am assuming $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a set where the "function is 1 for the rationals in the range $[-1,1]$ and is zero otherwise.

Comment: @johnwashburn almost: it's 1 at all of the rationals, but the one you mention also works. (There are many, many choices)

Comment: Can you explain your last paragraph?  You're proposing something like $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f) + 1_E$ where $E$ is some sort of fat Cantor set, having positive measure?  I don't buy that, since I don't think $\mathcal{F}(1_E)$ will have compact support.

Comment: So I understand the counter example.  The function, $f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t^2} * \text{sinc}(2t)$, has a Fourier transform of: $f(\omega) = e^{-\omega^2} \cdot 1_{[-1,1]}$ and function, $g(t) = f(t) + 1_{\mathbb{Q}}$, has the exact same Fourier transform: $f(\omega) = e^{-t^2} \cdot 1_{[-1,1]}$.  Since $f(t)$ is continuous and $g(t)$ is nowhere continuous, band-limited is not a sufficient condition to insure continuity on the real line even though $f(t) = g(t)$ almost everywhere.  Correct?

Comment: @JohnWashburn Yes, that's accurate.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, I should have modified the function on the other side of the transform, but it seems a.e. equivalence classes aren't the same for John's purposes (as I thought they might not be) so that one is superfluous anyways.

Comment: That then is an answer.  Delightful counter-example. Here is a possible repair:  If the additional restriction on $f(t)$ is $f(t) = \mathfrak{F}^{-1}\left\{ \mathfrak{F}\left\{ f(t) \right\}\right\}$, then does band-limited imply continuous on the real line?

Comment: @JohnWashburn Yes! Band limited implies $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is integrable, (it's continuous with compact support) so the inverse transform is given by an integral as well. But integrals are always continuous, so $f$ must be as well. In that context, band-limited functions such that $f(t)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(f(t)))$ are continuous.

Comment: Even for distributions possessing a Fourier transform that is a distribution of Dirac $\delta$ is not integrable?  My example function, $f_{1b}$, was chosen with some malice since $\lim\limits_{T \to \infty} \int\limits_{\omega = -T}^{T} \mathfrak{F}\left\{ f(t) \right\} d\omega = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20152/discussion-between-john-washburn-and-adam-hughes).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better statement, given Adam Hughes example, would be that if $f$ is band limited, then it's equal almost everywhere to some continuous function $g$. I believe that this is true -- it's certainly true for functions on $S^1$, where the FT lies in $L^2(\mathbb Z)$, and "band limited" means "FT is zero outside of some finite interval", for then the function is almost everywhere equal to the IFT of the FT, and this IFT is just a finite sum of trigonmetric functions.

I'm pretty sure the corresponding statement for $L^2[0, 1]$ is also true, but I'm no confident that I could prove it. :(

Since the OP won't say what space the function $f$ lies in :), I'll give a kind of hedged answer:

If the multiplication-convolution theorem holds for your function, along with a few  other assumptions, then band-limited does indeed imply continuous (in the sense of "equal to a continuous function a.e."). Here's why:

1. $\widehat{\mathrm{sinc}}$ is a box function $b$ (i.e., the indicator function for some interval). Let's suppose (by rescaling as needed) that the support of $\hat{f}$ is contained in that interval.
2. Then $\widehat{\mathrm{sinc}}* \hat{f} = \hat{f}$, so $\widehat{\widehat{\mathrm{sinc}}} \star \hat{\hat{f}} = \hat{\hat{f}}$.
3. Assuming that $\hat{\hat{f}} = f $ a.e., this means that $\mathrm{sinc} \star {f} = f$ (ae).
4. Since $\mathrm{sinc} \star {f}$ is continuous (because $\mathrm{sinc}$ is), we have that $f$ is continuous ae.

I'm making lots of assumptions here -- that $f$ is nice enough that convolution with sinc raises continuity from $C^{-1}$ to $C^0$, that the IFT of the FT of $f$ is still $f$ under whatever FT you're using, that the convolution-multiplication theorem holds, etc.

But you can also use this proof to show that $f$ is differentiable (by convolving with sinc again), twice differentiable, etc., so perhaps this is what those authors were thinking of when they made those claims. (I haven't read the papers/books to know whether my various assumptions are valid in their respective contexts.)

Comment: @AdamHughes: I think you two are at cross purposes.  Note that "equal almost everywhere to some continuous function" is not at all the same as "continuous almost everywhere".

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, that's true. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an answer could be this:

If a one-variable signal is bandlimited, it means it have a bounded maximum rate of change (as is explained [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51617/bounds-of-the-derivative-of-a-bounded-band-limited-function) ), so
$$ \sup_{t} \left| \frac{df(t)}{dt} \right| < \infty$$

Now, this make a restriction to $f(t)$, since if it has a discontinuity at a point $t_d$ it will happen that $f(t_d^-) \neq f(t_d^+)$ so at this point its derivative will diverge $f'(t_d) \to \infty$: you can describe this discontinuous function explicitly as another function $x(t)$ such as
$$x(t) \cong f(t)\cdot \theta(t_d^--t)+f(t)\cdot\theta(t-t_d^+)$$
with $\theta(t)$ the standard unitary step function, so by applying the differentiation on both sides will leads to:
$$\begin{array}{r c l} \frac{dx(t)}{dt} & \cong &  \frac{df(t)}{dt}\cdot \theta(t_d^--t)+f(t_d^-)\cdot \delta(t_d^--t)+\frac{df(t)}{dt}\cdot\theta(t-t_d^+)+f(t_d^+)\cdot\delta(t-t_d^+) \\
& = & \frac{df(t)}{dt}\cdot\left( \theta(t_d^--t)+\theta(t-t_d^+)\right)+\delta(t-t_d)\cdot\left(f(t_d^+)-f(t_d^-)\right)
\end{array}$$
where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac's Delta function/distribution, so at the point $t_d$ the function $|dx(t_d)/dt| \to \infty$ since $|\delta(0)| \cong \infty$.

With this, by contradiction, since a bandlimited signal can´t have an unbounded derivative, the function $f(t)$ can´t have a discontinuity of the kind $f(t_d^-) \neq f(t_d^+)$, so since it must happen that $\forall\, t_d\,,\, f(t_d^-) \equiv f(t_d^+)$ then the function must be continuous in this sense... but caution it still could have sharp tips like the absolute value function $|t|$ so $f'(t)$ could be discontinuous, but the step size $|f'(t_d^+)-f'(t_d^-)| < \infty$ must be finite so the maximum rate of change stills be finite... with this, meaning that it $f(t)$ could be "discontinuous" if other definitions of continuity are chosen (I don´t know if the condition $\forall\, t_d\,,\, f(t_d^-) = f(t_d^+)$ implies that $f(t)$ is going to be "uniformly continuous", or "absolutely continuous", etc.).

Comment: But since the Fourier transform of the derivative is equal to iω times the Fourier transform of the function, it is band limited as well... so your argument can be invoked recursively for all successive derivatives...

Comment: @LaurentJospin I started the answer with "I believe" because in math sometimes there are patological functions that have weird properties (like Cantor function), and maybe there is something that brokes it. But with some general assumptions, what you noted is true: if the function is "domain limited" or compact-supported, and fulfill the requisites of the [Paley–Wiener theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), then its Fourier Transf. is Analytic, and analytic imply is smooth. So indeed, a "common function" bandlimited FT should have a continuous original function

Comment: @LaurentJospin I learned about patological functions after giving this answer, and I think the analysis I did, being intuitive, is doesn't apply to them, like the Weierstrass function, is nowhere increassing neither decreassing.... also I learn about the Paley-Wienner Theorem after, will should work at least for square-integrable functions.